# Select count of foreign keys based on user defined limit

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have simplified the following mysql query that counts the number of times a primary key from table1 occurs as a foreign key in table2.

```
SELECT table1.*, COUNT(table2.id) AS 'value'

FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id

WHERE table1.lastname LIKE 'smith'

WHERE table1.firstname LIKE 'john'

GROUP BY table2.id;
```

I would like to modify it so that it only selects counts that are above a certain threshold, that is, if john smith's id occurs 10 times in table2, and my threshold is 20, his record will not be selected.

Comment: You cannot group by using just table2.id.All your SELECT columns should be used in the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: @deathonater, I take it `table2.id` is not unique?

Comment: @vutukuri, as it is, the query works well in terms of getting the counts and listing them with the corresponding records from table 1, i just need to be able to filter by the amount

Comment: @MichaelRushton, you are correct, table2.id is not unique

Comment: @deathonater Haven't you tried mellamokb's solution? It should help you.

Comment: You even can write HAVING COUNT(*) > x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GROUP BY table2.id
  HAVING COUNT(table2.id) >= @Threshold
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.*,table2.value as value
FROM table1,
(
SELECT table2.id, COUNT(table2.id) AS 'value'

FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id

WHERE table1.lastname LIKE 'smith' AND table1.firstname LIKE 'john'

GROUP BY table2.id
HAVING COUNT(table2.id)>=20
) table2
WHERE table1.id=table2.id;
```

Comment: thanks, but this isn't doing what I'd like, it seems to be returning a large amount of data even when I used very specific parameters.